# my requirement is, if new notification arrives, the content should add in the group

Tags: android, android-notifications

my requirement is simple, if the notif arrives it should added in the existing notification group like whats app

```
 public void showNotifications(String title, String message) {
        int SUMMARY_ID = 0;
        String GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL = "com.android.example.WORK_EMAIL";
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
        getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        StatusBarNotification[] notifications = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();

        String msg = message + String.valueOf(i++);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 
  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MYNOTIF")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        notificationManager.notify(notif.getID(), mBuilder.build());
}
```

this code send the notification, but i want to group it...
 any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setGroup()` method of Notification Builder class.

```
val GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL = "com.android.example.WORK_EMAIL"
val newMessageNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this@MainActivity, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
        .setContentTitle(emailObject.getSenderName())
        .setContentText(emailObject.getSubject())
        .setLargeIcon(emailObject.getSenderAvatar())
        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
        .build()
```

You can get more info here https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group